# Javascript If else statement trouble within a Function Validate()

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The following script should validate only certain input fields depending on the selection a user makes in a drop-down box (var problem).

The trouble I'm having is when the if statement runs for problem == 4 (below) and the user has filled in the corresponding cityid field, the alert (Alert#3) for the next if statement (problem == 5) is triggered. I only want Alert#3 to trigger if the user has selected problem == 5 from the drop-down AND has not filled in the model field.

The same trouble happens respectively when if statement runs for problem == 5.

```
function ValidateSOR()
{

    var user = document.SOR.User;
    var problem= document.SOR.Problem;
    var cityid = document.SOR.CityID;
    var errors1 = document.SOR.ErrorCodes1;
    var model = document.SOR.Model;
    var errors2 = document.SOR.ErrorCodes2;
    var software = document.SOR.SoftwareType;

    if (user.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your name.");
        user.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (problem.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        alert("Alert#1");
        problem.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (problem.selectedIndex == 4) 
    {
        cityid.focus();
    }
        else if (cityid.value == "")
    {
        alert("Alert#2");
        cityid.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (problem.selectedIndex == 5) 
    {
        model.focus();
    }
        else if (model.value == "")
    {
        alert("Alert#3");
        model.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (problem.selectedIndex == 6) 
    {
        software.focus();
    }
        else if (software.value == "")
    {
        alert("Alert#4");
        software.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: javascript is different from java.

Comment: Okay... does the difference relate to my problem or how I would solve it?

Comment: Orthogonal comment: consider using a validation library/plugin rather than writing bespoke validation. It tends to be much simpler and clearer.

Comment: And it is always better to know atleast some basics about what you are working.

Comment: So true.  One is always learning.  Thank you!

Comment: @user2170703 Pointy already gave the answer. Did you got where you lagged?

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning from the function when you discover that the problem is #4.  Thus, because it **is** 4, then it's not 5, and so the "else" part of that branch is taken.

*edit* — OK, let's look at the code:

```
if (problem.selectedIndex == 4) {
    cityid.focus();
}
else if (cityid.value == "") {
    alert("Alert#2");
    cityid.focus();
    return false;
}

if (problem.selectedIndex == 5) {
    model.focus();
}
else if (model.value == "") {
    alert("Alert#3");
    model.focus();
    return false;
}
```

If the index is 4, what happens?  This code runs:

```
  cityid.focus();
```

Then what?  The code proceeds to the next `if` statement:

```
if (problem.selectedIndex == 5) {
```

Now, if we just got through noticing that the index was 4, then what are the chances that it will be equal to 5?  Zero!  Thus, that comparison is guaranteed to be `false`, so we move to the `else` part.  Apparently, your "model.value" is the empty string, so that `if` statement succeeds. You get the alert.

I think your problems would be solved by bringing the logic of the code more in line with the logic of your validation process:

```
if (problem.selectedIndex == 4 || cityid.value == "") {
  cityid.focus();
  return false;
}
```

That way, if the index is 4 **or** if the city ID value is empty, then you'll treat that as an error with the city ID and exit the function. It won't matter what comes after that, because the `return` leaves the function at that point.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what your mean or how I would edit the code to do that.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: @user2170703 if the index is 4, then what happens after that `if` statement?  It will not return from the function, because the `return` statement is inside the `else` clause. Thus, it will move to the next test, and 4 is not equal to 5.

Comment: I guess I'm still a beginner at this and have a lot to learn! I do really well with visual examples.  Any chance you could rewrite one of the if and else statements to help?

Comment: @user2170703 I'll extend the answer.

Comment: I have extended the answer to provide explaination... not sure whether will be accepted otherwise Pointy mentioned, he will be putting things there.

Comment: @user2170703 you should spend some time trying to understand what is happening when the code runs. Use `console.log()` to add trace messages and to verify your assumptions about what code will or will not run. If you just say "it didn't work", nobody can help you.

Comment: Pointy, I understand your explanation and logic, but it didn't work.  I had the same trouble as before.  What could this mean?

Comment: @user2170703 it means that there is some other problem in your code. You have to put some work into it to discover exactly what's happening. Finding errors in your code is the most effective way to learn how code works.

Comment: Boy do I know that!  I've already spent over 24 hours trying to get it to work.  I don't know what a console.log() is.

Comment: @user2170703 `console.log()` is like `alert()` but far less invasive. It prints messages to the browser debug console. If you have not been using the browser debugging tools, your debugging efforts have been critically hampered.

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure each IF like so:

```
if (problem.selectedIndex == 4 || cityid.value == "") 
{
    cityid.focus();
    return false;
}

if (problem.selectedIndex == 5 || model.value == "") 
//and so on
```

so it returns either way and does not hit the next `if` statement

Comment: Here's the code that finally worked, and I had to change index numbers:

`if (problem.selectedIndex == 3){   
   if (cityid.value == ""){   
      window.alert("Give us the ID number, etc.");
      cityid.focus();
      return false;}
}
if (problem.selectedIndex == 4){ 
   if (model.value == ""){ 
      window.alert("Give us the model number, etc.");
      model.focus();
      return false;}
}
if (problem.selectedIndex == 5){ 
   if (software.value == ""){ 
      window.alert("What software is giving you trouble");
      software.focus();
      return false;}
}`